# Loop debug msg a json array

Tags: ansible

The original playbook is like this:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ intvlan.results[0].cde }}"
      - "{{ intvlan.results[1].cde }}"
      - "{{ intvlan.results[2].cde }}"
      - "{{ intvlan.results[3].cde }}"
```

And I want to change it into a loop.
So, I changed the code as below:

```yaml
vars:
  package:
    - { iterations: '1'}
    - { iterations: '2'}
    - { iterations: '3'}
    - { iterations: '4'}

tasks:
  - debug:
      msg:
        - "{{ intvlan.results[{{ item.iterations }}].cde }}"
        - "{{ intvlan.results[{{ item.iterations }}].cde }}"
        - "{{ intvlan.results[{{ item.iterations }}].cde }}"
        - "{{ intvlan.results[{{ item.iterations }}].cde }}"
    loop: "{{ package }}"
```

And I've got the msg as below:

> The error was: 'list object' has no attribute '{{item.iterations}}

What is the problem?

Comment: You might be able to loop with `intvlan.results` itself. Can you update the question with sample contents of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ansible, [moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names).

---

Other mistakes you have include:

- your `package.*.iterations` variables are `string` when your `intvlan.results` variable is a list, and, so, it expects `int` rather:

  ```yaml
  iterations: 1
  ```

  and **not**

  ```yaml
  iterations: '1'
  ```
- your `package.*.iterations` are in the range `1..4` when a list is zero-indexed, so `0..3` rather.

---

With all this:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ intvlan.results[item.iterations].cde }}"
  loop: "{{ package }}"
  vars:
    package:
      - iterations: 0
      - iterations: 1
      - iterations: 2
      - iterations: 3
```

---

Still, it seems to me like an overcomplicated way to go.
The simple way would be:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.cde }}"
  loop: "{{ intvlan.results }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop over debug message, then you should have debug message once and do the iteration from `loop`. Also I think you are looking to generate a sequence of numbers to target the *nth* elements of `intvlan.results`.

There is an option to loop over a `range` (of numbers).

Example:

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ intvlan.results[item].cde }}"
    loop: "{{ range(0, 4) | list }}"
```

Also as mentioned in my comment you may be able to iterate with `loop: "{{ intvlan.results }}"` itself.